# Можно ли в e-mail рассылке для прикрепленного файла задавать псевдоним?

Tags: email, рассылка

Файл хранится на сервере. Его название состоит из определенных id элементов из БД для того, чтобы легко его находить. 
Файл должен прикрепляться к e-mail письму. Когда письмо приходит пользователю, то он видит прикрепленный файл, как ему кажется, со странным названием.
Можно ли в e-mail рассылке для прикрепленного файла задавать псевдоним, чтобы в название было понятно пользователю? Есть ли определенные Email заголовки, для задания псевдонимов прикрепленных файлов? Или что-то в этом роде.
PS Просьба не писать ответы, наподобии "так назовите его на сервере нормально"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В письме есть *только предлагаемое* почтовому клиенту пользователя имя файла. И оно совершенно никак не связано с тем, что у вас есть на сервере. У вас как отправителя файла вообще может не быть и это не мешает отправить письмо с вложением.

За отображаемое имя файла отвечают заголовки `Content-Type` и `Content-Disposition`. Например,

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="parallel_paths_include_tlist_cost_v7.patch"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="parallel_paths_include_tlist_cost_v7.patch"
```

Вы можете указывать любое имя файла используя `US-ASCII` символы, о чём сказано в [`RFC 2183`](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt).